# Javascript RegEx.Test always returning true

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a value in a text input I need to verify as a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. Below is my code. I always get true regardless of what I enter in the text input. Otherwise function works well. Always displays an alert with the value I put in the text input.

```
function checkDate(date) 
    {
    var result;
    var expression = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/;
    result = expression.test(date.value);

        if(result=true)
        {
             alert(date.value);
        }

        else
        {
        alert("false finally");
        }


    }
```

Comment: `if (result == true)` or just `if (result)`

Comment: You're doing an assignment, and you need to do a conditional test. That's why some people write this as (true == result).

Comment: You should switch to using [Yoda](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/) conditions.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your a legend for such a fast response.

Comment: You assigned the value of _true_ to result in the if condition, instead of checking it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(result==true)
        {
             alert(date.value);
        }
```

instead having single "=" have "==" , else you can use like this

```
      if (result)
            {
                 alert(date.value);
            }
```

and always remember this

```
"1" == 1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
```

An example of type coercion at work. Basically anytime your value is the "same" but the type isn't then == works.

Please use === everywhere. There's no need to use ==. checking for types is always better. If something breaks then you can convert from type a to type b